# Create bitmap from file return null picture

Tags: java, android, image, file, bitmap

I wanted to do an app for sharing pictures from the gallery for learning and i want the picture to be renamed so i use a bitmap that retrieve the data of the picture. But the thing is the file is always returning null.
I have a code and i don't know where is the problem.

```
File file = new File(this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(), "logo");
if (!file.exists()) {
    file.mkdirs();
}
File iconf = new File(file, "icon_launcher.png");
iconf.createNewFile();
OutputStream ios = new FileOutputStream(iconf);

example.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, ios);
ios.flush();
ios.close();


//String uricon=       MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),iconf.getAbsolutePath(),"icon_launcher.png","drawing");

Uri iconurl = Uri.parse(iconf.getAbsolutePath());

Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
email.setType("image/png");

email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, iconurl);

startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(email, "Envoyer par mail"), 1);
```

Thank you in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have succeeded to make the code work, i forget to use a **FileProvider** because i didn't have an External Storage.So you have to use a **FileProvider** to use Internal Storage.